# Permanently change default size of open/save dialog boxes in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, save-as

When I go to save a newly created file in, say, Word, I like to click on "Browse" to open the traditional open/save dialog box that I'm still used to from older version of Windows.  My problem has always been that I would like these dialog boxes to be bigger than they are.  I've seen answers to the problem that will work while I'm still in the same session, but I'd like to know where I can set a value in the registry to permanently set the default size of such open/save dialog boxes.  That is unless, of course, we are not given such control over the UI.

Comment: This can be done in two way just with Windows 10. First, Start, Settings, System, and adjust the scale factor if you have a high resolution monitor. I use 125% on my high resolution laptop. Then (same place) Find a setting, type Text Size and select Make Text Bigger.  I use 110%. The combination of the two things makes Dialogue Boxes and items bigger.

Comment: BTW Office does not use Windows interface units. It uses its own multiplatform ones.

Comment: I'm searching solution for this too, the default size is too small, I want to have around 30% bigger size by default, haven't found a solution yet though.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and resolved it with the following steps: Open the File Dialog window using Notepad, adjust its size to your preference, and while pressing the "Control" key, close the Dialog window. The next time you open it, the size will be remembered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party tool like FileBox eXtender (http://www.hyperionics.com/files/index.asp) or Direct Folders (https://codesector.com/directfolders)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can find information on cofiguring Filebox Extender at http://www.hyperionics.com/files/hlp/html/configuration.html  You see some about configuring it at https://codesector.com/directfolders  There isn't a lot to it but it is pretty self explanatory.  Like you can add your favorite folders and then use the tray icon to start exploring without having to enter the path.  Also the options tab of Direct Files allows you to set the actual size of dialog boxes used for opening and saving files.  Again you can use your favorite folders for quick access when loading or saving.